# Django Admin Sorl-Thumbnail Link

Tags: python, html, django, django-admin, sorl-thumbnail

I am having trouble adding an html A tag around the img tag. When I add the A Tag with the variable, it stops showing the image in the Django Admin, but without the variable in the A tag it shows the image. I can't seem to figure this out, and possibility it may not be supported by sorl-thumbnail?

*UPDATE
Trying to pass two variables now with different thumbnail sizes, but it's not doing anything. I'm new working with definitions in Django Admin.

```
def screenshot_img(self, obj):
    if obj.screenshot:

            s = get_thumbnail(obj.screenshot,"x200",crop='center', quality=99)
            b = get_thumbnail(obj.screeshot,"x500",crop='center', quality=99)                

            return u'<a href="/im_troubleticket/media/%b"><img src="/im_troubleticket/media/%s"></a>' % (s, b)
    else:
            return u'No image'


screenshot_img.short_description = 'Picture'
screenshot_img.allow_tags = True
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the variable twice in the string, so you need to supply it twice:

```
return u'<a href="/im_troubleticket/media/%s"><img src="/im_troubleticket/media/%s"></a>' % (s, s)
```

EDIT: You have two new bugs in your code: First, you misspelled obj.screenshot. Second, the placeholders in your string indicate the type of data, not the name of the variable. See [Python String Formatting](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting). If you use descriptive variable names you are less likely to confuse the s in %s with the name of the variable.

```
thumb_small = get_thumbnail(obj.screenshot,"x200",crop='center', quality=99)
thumb_large = get_thumbnail(obj.screenshot,"x500",crop='center', quality=99)                

return u'<a href="/im_troubleticket/media/%s"><img src="/im_troubleticket/media/%s"></a>' % (thumb_small, thumb_large)
```

Comment: You think it's also possible to add another variable for a different size thumbnail, so when they click on the image it will have a bigger size? I was trying your fix and it works good with the same variable, I tried creating another variable with a larger size and it doesn't seem to work. I'll put the update in my post.

Comment: I edited my answer so I can post some code. A tip: do not rush yourself. You should be able to catch these oversights on your own if you calmly analyze your own code line by line.

Comment: Thank you so much for assisting, sometimes I look at the code too long and I confuse myself. For some reason I was thinking that "%s" - are physical variables, but they are just the location where the variables will be imputing to. This makes sense now.